# Which optimization type is this case?

Tags: matlab, optimization

[image]

The picture shows minimised case of my assignment, I try to minimize sum of all "y" values with using Matlab. These y values are changing with X matrix. So, y values are the functions of X matrix.

X variables are binary numbers and the sum of consecutive two numbers in the second row must be greater than or equal to 1. In addition, sum of consecutive three numbers in the third row must be greater than or equal to 1.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a mixed integer linear programming problem. (All linear constraints, and a binary one)

These can be solved with [intlinprog](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/intlinprog.html).

```
[x,fval] = intlinprog(f,intcon,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub)
```

Comment: If I use MILP, should I make this X matrix as a vector form?

Comment: [2] Can I create a loop for my last constraints(consecutive sums constraints)? Because my real case is very big so it can be very hard to write these constraints.

Comment: @SaimCanBakır Of course, but consider two things. 1. If you have followup questions, this is not the right place to ask. You could ask a new question if needed. 2. BEFORE you ask someone to help you with that, please try it yourself first. Hopefully you will succeed, and if you get stuck you can at least show what you have tried so far, making it easier for people to help you.

Comment: @SaimCanBakır I am not sure what you mean by a matrix as vector form. X should indeed be a matrix, if that is what you are asking. Note that the documentation that I linked to also contains examples.

Comment: If there is no way to write X matrix as a matrix, I try to write my optimization problem. Thanks for help

Comment: Finally matlab will show me the results. I want to obtain my result like;

[1 1 1 1 1 1;

1 0 1 0 1 0;

1 0 0 1 0 0]. My rows show some tasks and my columns show days, so it is easier to see which tasks should be applied in each day.